# Blur the FontView when SWRevealViewController menu opens

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I use a slide menu in my app which i created with `SWRevealViewController`. Now I want to blur the `FrontView` when the user opens the menu. How is that possible? My idea would be to have a blurView in the `FrontViewController` with an **alpha value of 0**. When the user opens the menu the **alpha value changes to 1**. My question is if there is a specific function which is called when the user opens the menu?

If possible the `blurView's` alpha value should change equally to the swipe which opens the menu: When the user uses the `GestureRecognizer` to open the menu, the movement of the `menuViewController` and the change of the **alpha value should go equal.**

I hope you can understand my problem.
Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been working on your question and this are my results,

[image]

First of all in the `SWRevealViewControllerDelegate` you have 3 methods to get noticed of changes on the revealViewController `panGestureRecognizer`

```
func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, panGestureBeganFromLocation location: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat) {
}

func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, panGestureMovedToLocation location: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat, overProgress: CGFloat) {
}

func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, panGestureEndedToLocation location: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat, overProgress: CGFloat) {
}
```

So you need make your `FrontViewController` as delegate of `SWRevealViewController`

like this `self.revealViewController().delegate = self`

and then using an extension from https://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial called `UIImage+ImageEffects` founded on the example code provided by the tutorial, we can create an image from frontViewController.view and apply the gaussian blur from the mentioned category this is the code

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {

    var imageBlur : UIImageView?
    var originalImage : UIImage?
    let maxRadius : CGFloat = 5.0
    let minRadius = 0
    var arrayOfImages : [UIImage]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        self.revealViewController().delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.originalImage = self.takeSnapShotOfView(self.view)
        self.imageBlur = UIImageView(image: self.originalImage)
        self.view.addSubview(self.imageBlur!)
    }

    func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, panGestureBeganFromLocation location: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat) {

        let image = self.originalImage
        self.imageBlur?.image = image?.applyFixedBlurWithRadius(CGFloat(progress*self.maxRadius))
    }

    func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, panGestureMovedToLocation location: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat, overProgress: CGFloat) {
        let image = self.originalImage
        self.imageBlur?.image = image?.applyFixedBlurWithRadius(CGFloat(progress*self.maxRadius))

    }

    func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, panGestureEndedToLocation location: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat, overProgress: CGFloat) {
        let image = self.originalImage
        self.imageBlur?.image = image?.applyFixedBlurWithRadius(CGFloat(progress*self.maxRadius))

    }

    func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition) {
        if(position == .Left)
        {
            self.imageBlur?.image = self.originalImage
        }
        if(position == .Right)
        {
            let image = self.originalImage
            self.imageBlur?.image = image?.applyFixedBlurWithRadius(CGFloat(1*self.maxRadius))
        }
    }

    func takeSnapShotOfView(view:UIView) ->UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height))
        view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }


}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: It is awesome! Thanks so much